# Appcelerator - barImage hides the title text

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

When I create a new window in Appcelerator I need to change the background image. This is done by setting “barImage”. The window itself is a child of a navigation group and has its own children. When I use the “barImage” parameter it hides the nav bar title text on the initial load of the window. If I navigate to its child window and then back the title text is displayed in the nav bar.

```
var sectionWindow  = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
    backgroundColor:'#fff',
    fullscreen:false,
    title:’My Sub Page',
    modal:true,
    barImage:'images/nav_bar.png'
});
```

How can I get the title text to consistently display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there are known issues with the barImage in the 1.7.2 release, please check the 1.8x CI builds where the issue has been addressed

Comment: Thanks, where can I get the 1.8x CI builds?